# After changing password still getting: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql

I just installed mysql 5.7.23 on my mac sierra 10.13.5.

I saved this to a notepad:

> 2018-09-02T05:39:56.919171Z 1 [Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: =su8S7ge4d4X
>
> If you lose this password, please consult the section How to Reset the Root Password in the MySQL reference manual.

I tried to log in using the password `mysql -u root -p =su8S7ge4d4X`

Got error:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tried to change password:

1. Stop the mysqld server.

   - **Mac OSX:** `System Preferences` > `MySQL` > `Stop MySQL Server`
2. Start the server in safe mode with privilege bypass

   - **From Terminal:** `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`
3. In a **new** terminal window:

   - `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root`
4. This will open the mysql command line. From here enter:

   - `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('NewPassword') WHERE User='root';`
   - `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
   - `quit`
5. Stop the mysqld server again and restart it in normal mode.

   - **Mac OSX (From Terminal):** `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart`

It doesn't look like any rows are being affected:

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('root') WHERE User='root';
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Still tired to login:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I have no idea what to do at this point.

Comment: Remove the space before your password, as described on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `mysql -u root -p` then hit enter. If it prompts for a password, then you type your password.

Comment: I did, it does not work.